# How to add items to Schematic and BOM without footprints in the PCB in Altium

Tags: pcb-design, design, altium, documentation

As part of the documentation for an Electronics project generated in Altium designer 17, I would like to add part number for items the project need, but are not part of the PCB.

For example in the schematic and PCB i have added :
Molex Mini Jr PCB mount Receptacle , However i am asked to include the mating Plug, Crimp and wire which is not a part of the pcb, but a part of the whole assembly.

**1. What is the Standard (and neat) way of doing this kind of documentation?**

**2. Is it possible to add these parts in the schematic but make altium understand they don't have footprint ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to simply change the item property 'Type' from Standard to **Mechanical**. This will still cause the item to output to the BOMs, but will not translate as a component with a PCB footprint.

This is something you can also set in the library definition by modifying the component's schematic symbol in its SCH library.

Answer (score 4):

Simply add them as a mechanical part. For example:

[image]

If you add a footprint, it **will** be included. If you don't Altium won't complain.

It will be included in the BOM.